# Domain Name Redirection with Path?

Tags: web, dns, hosting, web-hosting

I need your Help please!
I have a domain name that redirected to an other:

```
www.xxx.com ===> redirected to ===> www.yyy.com
```

If i write `www.xxx.com/photo.html`, i want to be redirected to `www.yyy.com/photo.html`.

It's possibl ?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602324/how-to-detect-an-incoming-request-with-php-script-from-a-cname-subdomain/30630937#30630937) to help illuminate the options. Please feel free to ask any additional questions after reading that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all pages of one domain to be redirected to other domain, following .htaccess code will redirects everything after the domain name on the url to the exact same copy on the new domain url:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```