# How to point naked domain and www to the same Heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, dns, subdomain, cloudflare

I create a simple Rails app and deployed it to Heroku. [This is my app](http://theorderapp.herokuapp.com/). I use Cloudflare to manage my DNS records and I try to achieve something like this:

[image]

This is all my current DNS records inside my Cloudflare:

[image]

**My problem**:

When I go to `ordr.my`, it's works like I wanted to.
But when I go to `www.ordr.my`, it returns `This webpage is not available` error (I'm using Chrome browser).

Am I doing any mistakes here?

How to achieve something like inside the image above?

**Note**:

I did my research by reading Heroku and CloudFlare docs. But I found no luck since I'm not able to understand them very clearly.

Reference:

1. [Heroku Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)
2. [Cloudflare Zone Apex](https://blog.cloudflare.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-root-domain-cname-supp/)
3. [Cloudflare CNAME Flattening](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root)

Comment: What is the output of `heroku domains` - have you added both your root (apex) domain and your www sub-domain?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @elithrar. It works after I added `www.ordr.my` inside my Heroku custom domain section. :)

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Heroku, but this might help some give some more insight to the roles for DNS and HTTP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602324/how-to-detect-an-incoming-request-with-php-script-from-a-cname-subdomain/30630937#30630937

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I added `www.ordr.my` into my Heroku custom domain section and change `ordr.my` CNAME (root domain) to my Heroku app just like below:

**Cloudflare**

[image]

**Heroku**

[image]