# How to configure DNS 'mask' name to cover ip and app name

Tags: dns, iis-7.5

I have deployed an app so its now in a virtual application folder on iis.  when i now access it is is ip/app name so something like 192.168.0.1/MyApp/....

Is there a way to mask that to be a single name so for example if I entered MyAppDev/ and run it will direct to that?

No really knwolage of iis or dns so any dummies guide to would be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

Link to previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602324/how-to-detect-an-incoming-request-with-php-script-from-a-cname-subdomain/30630937#30630937) to explain the various options. Then some more info about [IIS bindings](http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools.aspx)

Hope that helps.