# Rewrite one Domain to Another without changing Address bar

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I'm in the process of changing my website from one hosting to another, however I've got the problem of how to do this.

Basically the new site on the new hosting is due to go live on Monday. However the name-servers are being changed Friday. There is another domain that is going to be parked on the old hosting.

How would I (if there is a way) point the actual domain at the temporary domain without actually changing the address bar so:

User goes to `www.example.com` on Thursday and sees `www.example.com` because it is hosted on `HOST1`

`www.example123.com` gets parked on `www.example.com`'s hosting Friday and the name-servers for `www.example.com` are changed to `HOST2`.

When a user goes to `www.example.com` on Friday, Saturday or Sunday can I, and how would I, show the user `www.example123.com` but still keep the address bar as `www.example.com`

If there is a way to do this in either PHP or HTAccess rather than using the DNS settings that would be great. The reason we are doing this is so that when we actually go live with the site it doesn't take 2-24 hours to propagate through the internet and not be the same live time across the world.

I understand if this isn't doable but need to ask as its a precaution that my work are putting in place to avoid traffic going to the new site, and propagating early.

Thanks for any advice, assistance and solutions in advance

Comment: Why do you need `example123.com`? Why can't you host this content (presumably some kind of "holding page") on `example.com`, and make the switch on Monday?

Comment: Because we don't have access to the FTP of the previous host, it was managed in a CMS and was part of a template. Hence the switch in house

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602324/how-to-detect-an-incoming-request-with-php-script-from-a-cname-subdomain/30630937#30630937) discussing differences between redirect, rewrite, and virtual hosts.

What it sounds like you're trying to do can be accomplished by setting up your new content in the new location (using a new name for testing) and then configure a rewrite or redirect, depending on how you want the client's browser to treat it (also some SEO implications), on the *old* site to load the *new* site's content. Normally, I've done this load balancers in front of the servers, but it can be accomplished with mod_rewrite as well.

One of the concerns I would have is how dynamic your content is. If "switching" sites from old to new will disrupt your customers, then you would definitely want to push them off the old servers, either by redirect or rewrite, as soon as the new name comes online.

Comment: From the link you've shared it would be a rewrite that I would be after, and I wouldn't want to let the clients browser know its occured. What SEO Implications would there be?

Comment: Most of the SEO stuff I'm aware of relates to redirects vs the other methods. If you're using a rewrite, then the only SEO stuff I can think of would be if your content is identical across two different domains.