# How to Make Short Domian for article

Tags: dns, short

I need to short my article link from :

```
www.mydomain.com/20/2015/article-slug
```

To :

```
 http://onmbc.net/kjhs
```

What the steps to do that ?

Comment: Use a URL shortening service like http://goo.gl/ or http://bit.ly/

Comment: but this tow service not get me link like `http://onmbc.net/kjhs `

Comment: Do you specifically require `onmvc.net`? If so, is this a programing question? - doesn't seem like it

Comment: Without any details about what language/framework/technologies you're using, I'm not sure this is even related to programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Link to previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602324/how-to-detect-an-incoming-request-with-php-script-from-a-cname-subdomain/30630937#30630937) explaining difference between redirect, rewrite, and virtual hosts. To get a link to a specific domain, onmbc.net, you will need to engage the owners of that domain.

Comment: its not redirect, its short link for big link to use it in social, How can engage  ??

Comment: I gave you that link because it sounds like you need to enhance your understanding of the difference between redirects, and rewrites. But you can't simply hand out other people's domain entries as your own. Do you have any sort of relationship with them? You can check their whois information for contact information: http://bgp.he.net/dns/onmbc.net#_whois